# github and local repository on NAS (ZFS) file modes

Tags: git, file-permissions, samba

After doing

```
git clone https://github.com/jdlugosz/parNext.wiki.git wiki
```

I find that all the files are immediately showing as modified

> old mode 100644
>   new mode 100755

Oddly, a `get reset --hard` does not fix it.  I can do a chmod directly, but I worry as to why git set them the wrong way when checking out, and will this become a permanent thorn as I continue to use that local repository?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. While the git data structure can technically store 
unix mode bits in its trees, it was found early on in git's history that 
respecting anything beyond a simple executable bit ended up being more 
cumbersome for git's normal use cases (i.e., people storing code or 
other shared files in a repository).

We could add in a config option to respect file modes, but it has 
generally been seen as not worthwhile. It solves only a part of the 
general metadata problem, as it omits owner and group names or ids, as 
well as extended metadata like ACLs.

(Source: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/file-mode-td6467904.html#a6469081)

Comment: If git doesn't store the bits, why does it complain that they are different?  Why aren't files written with the bits it thinks they should have?